# RegistryKey can be referenced in ASP.NET Core 2.0 app but not in a Console .NET 2.0 Core app

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I can reference RegistryKey class in a ASP.NET Core 2.0 app but not in a Console .NET 2.0 Core App. Why is that?

I get the following compilation error when I try to reference OpenBaseKey() (a static method) in RegistryKey.

```
The name 'RegistryKey' does not exist in the current context
```

I'm using VS2017 and my project is targeting .NET Core 2.0 (not Standard 2.0).

Answer (score 8):

Probably your ASP.NET Core application is targeting .NET Framework and not .NET Core. Add the required NuGet package to get Registry API.

It's `Microsoft.Win32.Registry` ([here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Win32.Registry/)). But then you lose portability and can't run the application on Linux and MacOS anymore.